# Why does a song say "put me six foot down"?

Tags: grammar, lyrics

Here is the [lyric](https://www.google.com/search?q=put+me+six+foot+down+lyrics):

> I told you on the day we wed
> I was gonna love you 'til I's dead
> Made you wait 'til our wedding night
> That's the first and the last time I wear white

> So if the ties that bind ever do come loose
> Tie them in a knot like a hangman's noose
> 'Cause I'll go to heaven or I'll go to hell
> Before I'll see you with someone else

> Put me in the ground
> Put me six **foot** down

As far as I can tell it should rather be "put me six **feet** down", what am I missing?

Comment: It is common in idiomatic English to use the singular _foot_ instead of the plural in phrases such as _six foot tall_ ("six feet tall") and _six foot under_ ("six feet under").

Comment: ...and one reason for that might be that we can say "a six-foot hole" (or even _a four-inch square_). Units are sometimes kept in the singular.

Comment: If you are learning English, I would not pay too close heed to song lyrics. Lyricists, like poets, are given wide artistic license. Lyrics may not only be non-standard or non-grammatical, but may be totally nonsensical, and chosen only because they sound evocative, or provocative, or happen to fit rhythm or rhyme as desired by the author. In lyrics, in other words, there is no such thing as *should*. If you can find examples of this in prose, then the question is more answerable.

Answer (score 5):

While measuring a length using a  ruler or other device with markings, the markings that occur at each 1-foot interval can be talked about using the term "foot" rather than feet.

A yardstick, for example, has a 1-foot mark, a 2-foot mark, and a 3-foot mark.  A distance contains a number of feet but a point on a line happens at a foot mark, or just foot for short.

The song is referring to a six-foot mark in the ground, which is a standard grave depth and [goes back to the 1600's](http://mentalfloss.com/article/31633/how-did-6-feet-become-standard-grave-depth).

Answer (score 3):

It's an idiom that means "**to bury someone**".

> Bodies are buried six feet below the surface. "**Why are they?**" you might ask.

Well when England was being ravaged by the Bubonic Plague in order to limit the outbreak, and spread of the disease, The Lord Mayor of London enacted a series of rules with regard to dealing with the bodies of those who died from the plague. This included a mandate that all dead must be buried in graves that had been dug a minimum of six feet deep. *(Scientifically, this “**solution**” to bury bodies six feet under was ineffective in reducing the transfer of the plague since the fleas quickly leave its dead host and find a new live one)*

Ok, so when the word foot is used as an adjective it should not be pluralised as there are no plural adjectives in English. For example: a match box, in that sentence the word 'match' is an adjective describing the box. So we would say "bury me six foot down" because the measurement (noun), foot, becomes adjectivial and describes the depth. However, in modern times when talking about measurement foot and feet have become interchangeable. However, when talking about distance you always say feet unless it 1 foot away.